Как сделать вывод в детальной странице товара название товара?
Есть код:
Он, в принципе, выводит название торгового предложения. Но если меняю, например, цвет товара, то название он не меняет, приходится обновлять страницу. Подскажите пожалуйста, как переделать код, чтобы при изменении страницы сразу подтягивалось название из торгового предложения?
